# Popup with simultaneous page redirection in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, popup

I want a PHP page that triggers a popup on pageload, and then redirects to another (3rd party) page while the popup is in the foreground. Is this possible with PHP (and perhaps plain JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. You should make simple pop up with javascript but if you want to load a page beneath it the page should open in iframe ( at least that's the most simple way I can think of )

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to use an iframe solution. Is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: If it's 3rd party I don't think so. If you have access to the other page you can redirect to it and before the page starts loading you display your pop up.